# To find a particular string from multiples text files in the same directory

Tags: python-3.x

I am finding a string, for example "error", from a multiple text files. The multiple text files are within a similar directory. After finding, it must be able to print that line containing the string.

So far, I have only been successful on searching and printing out the string from one text file.

In the below code, I tried to create a list of the filenames in the directory; the list is called `logz`, but it printed out nothing. It only worked when the `logz` in line 10 is listed as a `TXT` file.

The desired output should be something like this:

> Line 0: asdasda error wefrewfawvewvaw
>
> Line 3: awvawvawvaw error afvavavav
>
> Line 6: e ERROR DSCVSVWASEFVEWVWEVW

Here is my code:

```
import re
import sys
import os

logz = [fn for fn in os.listdir(r'my text file directory') if fn.endswith('.txt')]

err_occur = [] # The list where we will store results.
pattern = re.compile(" error ", re.IGNORECASE)


try: # Try to:
    with open ('logz', 'rt') as in_file: # open file for reading text.
        for linenum, line in enumerate(in_file): 
            if pattern.search(line) != None: 
                err_occur.append((linenum, line.rstrip('/n'))) 
                print("Line ", linenum, ": ", line, sep='')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following program as an example for writing yours. Replace the `'.'` in line 5 with the path to your text file directory. Line 9 can be modified as needed to search for words other than `'error'` as well. You will need to be running Python 3.6 if you want to use `f''` strings (line 10).

```
import pathlib


def main():
    for path in pathlib.Path('.').iterdir():
        if path.suffix.lower() == '.txt':
            with path.open() as file:
                for line, text in enumerate(file):
                    if 'error' in text.lower():
                        print(f'Line {line}: {text}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: After asking a question and receiving an answer, you may want to consider the suggestions given here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)